# Array Length in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am an absolute beginner to programming and Javascript and was watching one of Douglas crockford's videos where he says the following

> Arrays unlike objects have a special length member
>
> It is always 1 larger than the highest integer subscript

In this array

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

`a.length` equals to 7.

So I am not quite sure what 1 larger than highest integer subscript means...? Is it just an outdated piece of info from a older version of Javascript or am i missing something ?

Comment: Arrays in Javascript begin at `0`, so in your example, `a[0]` is `1`, and `a[6]` is `7`. It's less confusing with characters: `var abc = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']`, where `abc[0]` is `a`, and `abc[6]` is `g`.

Comment: The subscript of an array refers to its index.

Comment: @JaredFarrish That's an answer!

Comment: And just in case it ins't clear, the _subscript_ is the index like `[0]` or `[4] or [6]`.

Comment: @user1313697 Then do the guys who answered a favor, and accept the one you like most.

Comment: @isim - of course! :) and done..there seems to be a time limit to when i can accept the answer.

Comment: @user1313697 No problem :) And if you are keen on knowing WHY the length is 1 larger than the highest subscript, just google `c/c++ array, pointer, pointer arithmetic.`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It just means that the length of an array is <s>always</s>* its largest index + 1.

Consider:

```
var a = [];
a[6] = 'foo';
console.log(a.length) //7
a[20] = 'bar';
console.log(a.length) //21
```

*actually not always, like for example when you use Array constructor with number argument: `var a = new Array(5)`, the array is empty, but it has its `length` explicitely set to `5`

Comment: @RobG That's a special case. As 15.4.2.2 of ES5 specification states: "If the argument len is a Number and ToUint32(len) is equal to len, then the length property of the newly constructed object is set to ToUint32(len)". So this has nothing to do with elements inside, this explicitely sets the `length`.

Answer (score 0):

length equals to no of elements in the array and index starts from 0 , understand it like you are not starting with 1 instead with 0 so you will have 1 less than total elements(length). so

length = total elements

and

last index = length-1;

Answer (score -1):

Arrays are indexed from 0 (first element), but length is from 1 (one element) (array won't have length of -1 if there won't be no elements, the length would be 0; if there are 2 elements, second element will have the index of 1 and the length will be 2).

Comment: Not my down vote, but length begins at zero. Given `var a = []`, *a* has a length of zero.

Answer (score -2):

Indexes and lengths are different. While a JavaScript array will start at 0, the length will always be the true number. This is helpful since on a slice, the last number is NOT inclusive.